# [System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I am trying to select a user from my `default_information.aspx.cs` page and display that user information on my `registration.aspx` page where I already created a registration form.

I am getting `System.NullReferenceException:Object reference not set to an instance of an object` error. Please help me. I've given the main part of it. I debugged it. I found every data is selected from my DB in **string** `strusername`,`strpassword`. But code breaks on `usernametxt.Text = strusername;` when i try to show username or password on that text field.

default_information contains

```
    protected void gridviewprofile_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        registration objdef = new registration();
        string username = gridviewprofile.Rows[gridviewprofile.SelectedIndex].Cells[1].Text;
        objdef.displayuser(username);
    }
    protected void update_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("registration.aspx");
    }
```

registration.aspx contains

```
    protected void register_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        user objuser = new user();
        objuser.username = usernametxt.Text;
        objuser.password = passwordtxt.Text;
        objuser.email = emailtxt.Text;
        objuser.Save();
    }
    public void displayuser(string username)
     {   user obj = new user();
        DataSet objDataset = obj.profile(username);
        string strusername = objDataset.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString();
        string strpassword = objDataset.Tables[0].Rows[0][1].ToString();
        string stremail = objDataset.Tables[0].Rows[0][2].ToString();      
        usernametxt.Text = strusername;
        passwordtxt.Text = strpassword;
        emailtxt.Text = stremail;            
    }
```

user class contains

```
public class user
{    
    public void Save()
    {
        clssqlserver obj = new clssqlserver();
        obj.insertuser_info(Username,Password,Email);                           
    }
     public DataSet profile(string username)
    {
        clssqlserver obj = new clssqlserver();
        return obj.getalluser_info(username);
    }

}
```

clssqlserver contains

```
    public DataSet getalluser_info(string username)
    {
        string connectionstring = "Data Source=localhost\\mssql;Initial Catalog=blooddb;Integrated Security=True";
        SqlConnection objconnection = new SqlConnection(connectionstring);
        objconnection.Open();
        string command = "Select * from login_donor where username='" + username + "' ";
        SqlCommand objcommand = new SqlCommand(command, objconnection);
        DataSet objdataset = new DataSet();
        SqlDataAdapter objadapter = new SqlDataAdapter(objcommand);
        objadapter.Fill(objdataset);
        objconnection.Close();
        return objdataset;
    }
    public bool insertuser_info(string username,string password,string email)

      {     string connectionstring = "Data Source=localhost\\mssql;Initial Catalog=blooddb;Integrated Security=True";
            SqlConnection objconnection = new SqlConnection(connectionstring);
            objconnection.Open();
            string strInsertCommand = "insert into login_donor values('"+ username +"','"+ password + "','"+email+"')";
            SqlCommand objcommand = new SqlCommand(strInsertCommand, objconnection);
            objcommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            objconnection.Close();
            return true;
     }
```

Comment: In wich line you het the error?

Comment: Check objDataset.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0

Comment: Is `usernametxt` null, by any chance? Try putting a breakpoint on that line.

Comment: usernametxt.Text = strusername; here i got this error message..code worked fine.every data that i want to select has been selected properly..like string strusername=riasat,strpassword=1234..when it on that line usernametxt.Text is not showing output..but selecting properly

Comment: try..usernametxt.Text = strusername.toString()

Comment: @ridoy - that will not help if `usernametxt` is null (which it probably is), and now also fail if `strusername` is null (which shouldn't happen - a DbNull.Value in the dataset would become an empty string)

Comment: Do you debug objDataset.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString() gets value from DB?

Comment: Logically usernametxt.Text=objDataset.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString() will print the value to textbox,but if you still find null exception there that means there are problems in fetching data from db,especially in objDataset.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString() and DataSet objDataset = obj.profile(username).So check these values first.

Comment: @ridoy sir: objDataset.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString() fetching exectly the value that i want..tostring() not helping..giving the same error..

Comment: Does passwordtxt.Text and emailtxt.Text print something or same error there?

Comment: Lets do a basic check,in your displayuser() write if(username==null) MessageBox.show("value null") else {your rest code}.This will examine whether displayuser() get value from selected index of gridview.

Comment: thankz every one for giving your opinion...i ve learned a lot from you..thankz a lot for supporting me..i ve found the solution which is given bellow...check it out..:)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using the asp.net create user wizard control.Because your controls are buried inside another container, you have to be rewarded after some little excavation..Lets start digging......

Using the wizard which is already accessible locate your text box

```
TextBox  usernametxt= (TextBox)CreateUserWizard.FindControl("usernametxt");
usernametxt.Text = strusername;
```

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

You should check this line

```
string strusername = objDataset.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString();
```

you are trying to access directly `objDataset.Tables[0]`, what if there is no user with the supplied username to this method `getalluser_info(string username)`, will the `dataset` fill the table.

you should first check whether there is any table in the `dataset` or not.

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

well i ve found the solution...i was passing Data Between Webforms in worng way..here is the link which helps me: http://dotnetslackers.com/community/blogs/haissam/archive/2007/11/26/ways-to-pass-data-between-webforms.aspx
here is the solution

default_information.aspx contains

protected void gridviewprofile_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)

```
    {   string username = gridviewprofile.Rows[gridviewprofile.SelectedIndex].Cells[1].Text;
        Response.Redirect("registration.aspx?id="+username);
    }
```

registration.aspx contains:

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)

```
    {   
        string queryStringID = Request.QueryString["id"];
        displayuser(queryStringID);
    }
```

public void displayuser(string username)

```
     {   user obj = new user();
        DataSet objDataset = obj.profile(username);
        string strusername = objDataset.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString();
        string strpassword = objDataset.Tables[0].Rows[0][1].ToString();
        string stremail = objDataset.Tables[0].Rows[0][2].ToString();      
        usernametxt.Text = strusername;
        passwordtxt.Text = strpassword;
        emailtxt.Text = stremail;            
    }
```